# MS Access Visual Basic Group Recordset and modify values

Tags: linq, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have an Access Database where I have a defined query.

This query has 3 fields "Category", "Points" and "Place"
Multiple records can have the same Category entry.

What I now need to do is group query records by "Category".
In each of these subgroups order by "Points"
Edit "Place" in subgroup starting from "1st" and going to "2nd" and so on.
Repeat for next group till there are no more groups.

Maybe it will be easier if I say that the purpose is to assign awards (1st award, 2nd, 3rd (and so on) in different age groups according to points scored by a player).

I am a .NET programmer so I Immediately thought about LINQ but there is no linq here;/

Is there any other better way than to do separate sql requests and then sorting by Points?

Ok so here is the recordset I have (with Place column already filled, originally its empty and this is how it should be filled):

ID    CATEGORY    POINTS    PLACE
 
----------------------------------
 
1   CAT1       8        2
 
1   CAT1       10       1 
 
1   CAT2       12       2
 
1    CAT2      11       3
 
1    CAT2      13       1
 
1    CAT3      12       1
 
1    CAT3      9         3
 
1    CAT3      3         4
 
1   CAT3       10      2

I don't know up front how many categories are there.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and include your query.  That way, we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: my query is just "select Id, Category, Points, Place from sometable", you would like to see results of a query?

Comment: Can you please post sample data and expected output?

Comment: You should probably consider what to do for ties. e.g on ties for 2nd you could do (1,2,2,4) or you could do  (1,2,2,3). Also going from .net to access-vba is ... unpleasant. Is there any reason you can just use .net as the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading documentation thoroughly I found that I would have to do a lot of sorting and grouping by hand so I eventually decided it is not worth it and switched to writing a desktop C# app which operated on this database. From there everything was obvious and a lot faster

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by separate SQL requests.  In VBA, you could use a single SQL request to fill a temp table with your data (plus an empty "PLACE" column), then use a recordset based on a similar query (like yours but against the temp table with "ORDER BY Category, Points DESC" added).  Then loop through that recordset and assign the score (using recordset.edit & .update etc.).  (But if you're a .Net programmer, I'm probably not telling you anything you don't already know...)